# Passing params array as each individual argument

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have parameters as an object array, but I would like to pass each individual key into a different function instead of passing the array. Here is a code example:

```
FunctionOne("variableOne", "variableTwo");

public void FunctionOne(params object[] args) {
    FunctionTwo(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just grab the array argument you want:

```
FunctionOne("variableOne", "variableTwo");

public void FunctionOne(params object[] args) {
    FunctionTwo(args[0]);
}
```

So if you want every single argument, you can iterate with a foreach loop:

```
FunctionOne("variableOne", "variableTwo");

    public void FunctionOne(params object[] args)
    {
        foreach (object item in args)
        {
            FunctionTwo(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want each parameter of the argument though, from no arguments to a huge number.

Comment: please explain it differently, I can't see what you want to achieve :( I've updated the answer to explain how to iterate through every single argument, but I'm not sure if that was your problem :/

Comment: My apologies, so like, I want to be able to run FunctionTwo with each argument like so:
FunctionTwo( arg1, arg2, arg3, ... )
Instead of running the whole function each time with a new argument

Comment: @GlorifiedPig And what if the number of items passed as `params` doesn't match your `FunctionTwo` signature? You will need to be explicit e.g. `FunctionTwo(args[0], args[1], // etc.`, which will throw an exception if there are too few items. The only other way is to use reflection.

Comment: The thing is, the function I'm pointing it to also uses params.

Comment: @GlorifiedPig I don't get it, if your second method also uses params, where is the problem to pass args as a parameter? If you only want (for example) the first 3 params of the args passed in function one, you can declare a new object[] variable and fill it with a for loop, then pass this variable to Functiontwo, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with the arguments array of dynamic size you can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to achieve this

```
typeof(YourClassName).GetMethod(nameof(FunctionTwo)).Invoke(this, args);
```

But be aware that this kind of operations are much slower than calling method directly. You can also save `MethodInfo` in a static variable to call .GetMethod() only once like so:

```
private static MethodInfo FunctionTwoMethodInfo = typeof(YourClassName).GetMethod(nameof(FunctionTwo));
```

And than call it like so:

```
FunctionTwoMethodInfo.Invoke(this, args);
```